# Ruby pluralizing the controller in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am new to ruby world and following tutorials to create a simple application. I am having a problem to create a form. I followed this link: 
[What is the Rails3 equivalent of start_form_tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919846/what-is-the-rails3-equivalent-of-start-form-tag)

but I am getting `undefined method people_path for #<#<Class:0x287c670>:0x2879370>`

my controller is Persons and I have this in route file: `resource :persons`

so probably ruby is trying to pluralize the Persons. I have no idea how to fix this issue and google search also does not seem to be helping.

Comment: Please post snippets of your routes, controller and view code please. This should be an easy and quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `resource :persons` try this:

```
resources :people
```

And your controller would be `PeopleController`

Comment: @Vijay Dev : why the singular version ?

Comment: use the singular if there is only one logical resource and you don't need ID's to find the right one. It depends on your situation. Most site have only one session or account for example, namely your own, you cannot access other accounts, so no need to use an ID.

Comment: oh as a rule, when you use `resource`, you should use singular, when you use `resources`, you should use the plural